# Range and null space of a diagonalizable linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I am studying linear algebra by Hoffman Kunze. In the introductory part of chapter 6, I have the following:

> Here is an illustration of what we have in mind. Perhaps the simplest matrices to work with, beyond the scalar multiples of the identity, are the diagonal matrices:
> $$
> D=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
> c_{1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
> 0 & c_{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & c_{3} & \cdots & 0 \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & c_{n}
> \end{array}\right]\tag{6-1}
> $$
> Let, $T$ be a linear operator on an $n$-dimensional space $V$. If we could find an ordered basis $B=\left\{\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{n}\right\}$ for $V$ in which $T$ were represented by a diagonal matrix $D$ [as in (6-1)], we would gain considerable information about $T$. For instance, simple numbers associated with $T$, such as the rank of $T$ or the determinant of $T$, could be determined with little more than a glance at the matrix $D$. We could describe explicitly the range and the null space of $T$. Since $[T]_{B}=D$ if and only if
> $$
> T \alpha_{k}=c_{k} \alpha_{k}, \quad k=1, \ldots, n
> $$
> the range would be the subspace spanned by those $\alpha_{k}$ 's for which $c_{k} \neq 0$ and the null space would be spanned by the remaining $\alpha_{k}$ 's. Indeed, it seems fair to say that, if we knew a basis $B$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $[T]_{B}=D$, we could answer readily any question about $T$ which might arise.

**My Doubt:**

Here how does it conclude that the range would be the subspace spanned by those $\alpha_{k}$ 's for which $c_{k} \neq 0$ and the null space would be spanned by the remaining $\alpha_{k}$ 's ? Please explain it with proof or any theorem that they have used and why is it true for the case of daigonal matrices only.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is "$(6-1)$" supposed to be a tag on the display?

Comment: 6-1 actually is the numbering given to the diagonal matrix. I couldn't type it correctly.

Comment: Use `\tag` to add a numbering to the equation; I've fixed the display.

Comment: Do you know the definition of nullspace? It follows immediately by the definition. The rank-nullity theorem is relevant here.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Yes, I know the definition of nullspace, but I can't understand why is it obvious using the rank nullity theorem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Esha When $c_k$ is zero, it zeroes out that coordinate in the vector it acts on. So say I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix with $c_1=0, c_2=1$. The image of the column vector $(x,y)^T$ under this transformation will be $(0,y)^T$. The nullspace will be $(x,0)^T$ and it's non-trivial because $c_1=0$. Note that these will always be orthogonal projections. The rank nullity theorem is optional here as you can see the rank of the matrix directly but it lets you see how the zero and non-zero entries decompose the domain into these two spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If $c_k\ne0$, then $\alpha_k$ belongs to the range of $T$, since it is equal to $T\left(\frac1{c_k}\alpha_k\right)$. On the other hand, if $v$ belongs to the range of $T$, then $v=T(a_1\alpha_1+a_2\alpha_2+\cdots+a_n\alpha_n)$ for some scalars $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$. In other words, $v=a_1T(\alpha_1)+a_2T(\alpha_2)+\cdots+a_nT(\alpha_n)$. But this is a linear combination of those $T(\alpha_k)$'s for which $c_k\ne0$. Since $T(\alpha_k)$ is a multiple of $\alpha_k$, this proves that the range of $T$ is the span of those $\alpha_k$'s such that $c_k\ne0$.

On the other hand, if $c_k=0$, $T(\alpha_k)=c_k\alpha_k=0$. So, $\alpha_k\in\ker T$. And if $v\in\ker T$, and $v$ cannot be written as a linear combination of those $\alpha_k$'s such that $c_k\ne0$, then $v=a_1\alpha_1+a_2\alpha_2+\cdots+a_n\alpha_n$, where, for some $k$, $a_k\ne0$. But$$0=T(v)=a_1c_1\alpha_1+a_2c_2\alpha_2+\cdots+a_nc_n\alpha_n.$$Since the $\alpha_k$'s are linearly independent and some $c_k$'s are equal to $0$, you must have $a_kc_k=0$ those $k$'s such that $c_k\ne0$. So, $a_k=0$ for those $k$'s. And this proves that $v$ is a linear combination of those $\alpha_k$'s such that $c_k=0$.